# Populate powerpoint presentation with database values

Tags: c#, sql, powerpoint

Somewhere in my application I need to create a powerpoint slides and populate it with DB values. I am able to create the slides using a local template. But I am not getting any idea how to populate it with DB values. I searched web and found [**this**](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/157867-Create-power-point-slide-charts-using-c-net.aspx)  but it isn't helping me out. There is no chart or graph I want to populate. It is just simple text based on DB values.
Can someone help me here ?

Comment: The link you gave, helps you to create a table, what are you looking for? You simply need to return the DB values and for each row, to create a new table in Powerpoint and to populate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This following code allows you to create a new slide, to select it and to add values to a table. You simply need now to read the DB and fill it in.

```
int newaddslidecounter = 0; // checking how many new slides have to be inserted in order to split the table
int startmultiplicator=1; // used in order to return current table row that must be pasted in new table
int amountrowsshown =7; // amount of shown rows per table
int fontsize = 12;
// set position of new table/chart
int topsize = 100;
int leftsize = 100;
int widthsize = 150;
int heightsize = 150;
Boolean alreadycreated = false; // checks if a table has already been created
//Resizing all tables
//and insert new Excel table instead while importing data from Excel table
//used for visualization of data
foreach (PowerPoint.Slide slide in presentation.Slides)
            {
                slide.Select();
                //loop through all shapes in slide
                foreach (PowerPoint.Shape pptshape in slide.Shapes)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Shape type : " + pptshape.Type.ToString());
                    //check if current shape is a table
                    //in order to do the manipulation
                    if (pptshape.Type.ToString().Equals("msoTable"))
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= pptshape.Table.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 1; j <= pptshape.Table.Columns.Count; j++)
                            {
                                /// checks if the module of the current row and the amount of maximum
                                /// shown rows to be visible in table is the same
                                // Console.WriteLine("row= " + i + " col= " + j);
                                if ((i % amountrowsshown) == 0 && alreadycreated == false)
                                {
                                    PowerPoint.Table objTable = null;
                                    /// Add new slide if table requires more than one slide
                                    if (newaddslidecounter == 0)
                                    {
                                        /// Add new table object in the slide                                        
                                        objTable = presentation.Slides[slide.SlideIndex].Shapes.AddTable(amountrowsshown, pptshape.Table.Columns.Count, topsize, leftsize, slide.Master.Width - widthsize, slide.Master.Height - heightsize).Table;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        presentation.Slides.Add(slide.SlideIndex + newaddslidecounter, NetOffice.PowerPointApi.Enums.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutClipArtAndVerticalText);
                                        /// Add new table object in the slide                                        
                                        objTable = presentation.Slides[slide.SlideIndex + newaddslidecounter].Shapes.AddTable(amountrowsshown, pptshape.Table.Columns.Count, topsize, leftsize, slide.Master.Width - widthsize, slide.Master.Height - heightsize).Table;
                                    }
                                    int incrementer = 1;
                                    /// Run through the created new table and paste all the previous table values
                                    for(int k=startmultiplicator;k<=i;k++)
                                    {
                                        for(int l=1;l<=pptshape.Table.Columns.Count;l++)
                                        {
                                           objTable.Cell(incrementer,l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text=pptshape.Table.Cell(k,l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                                           objTable.Cell(incrementer, l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = fontsize;
                                        }
                                        incrementer++;
                                    }
                                    startmultiplicator += amountrowsshown;
                                    alreadycreated = true;
                                    newaddslidecounter++;
                                }
                            }
                            alreadycreated = false;
                        }
                        /// In case is still some rows left which haven't been considered
                        /// we copy those in a new table
                        //Console.WriteLine("Create new table before leaving");
                       // Console.WriteLine(startmultiplicator);
                        if (startmultiplicator <= pptshape.Table.Rows.Count)
                        {
                            PowerPoint.Table objTable = null;
                            if (startmultiplicator < amountrowsshown)
                            {
                                /// Add new table object in the slide
                                objTable = presentation.Slides[slide.SlideIndex].Shapes.AddTable(amountrowsshown, pptshape.Table.Columns.Count, topsize, leftsize, slide.Master.Width - widthsize, slide.Master.Height - heightsize).Table;    
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                /// Don't add new slide for last rows
                                presentation.Slides.Add(slide.SlideIndex + newaddslidecounter, NetOffice.PowerPointApi.Enums.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutClipArtAndVerticalText);
                                // Add new table object in the slide
                                objTable = presentation.Slides[slide.SlideIndex + newaddslidecounter].Shapes.AddTable(amountrowsshown, pptshape.Table.Columns.Count, topsize, leftsize, slide.Master.Width - widthsize, slide.Master.Height - heightsize).Table;
                            }
                            int incrementer = 1;
                            /// Run through the created new table and paste all the previous table values
                            for (int k = startmultiplicator; k <= pptshape.Table.Rows.Count; k++)
                            {
                                for (int l = 1; l <= pptshape.Table.Columns.Count; l++)
                                {
                                    objTable.Cell(incrementer, l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = pptshape.Table.Cell(k, l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                                    objTable.Cell(incrementer, l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = fontsize;
                                }
                                incrementer++;
                            }
                            objTable.Application.Top = topsize;
                            objTable.Application.Left = leftsize;
                            objTable.Application.Width = slide.Master.Width - widthsize;
                            objTable.Application.Height = slide.Master.Height - heightsize;
                        }
                        pptshape.Delete();
                    }

                }
                newaddslidecounter=0;
                startmultiplicator=1;
            }
```

**Edited:

Code source for reading data from DB
[Reading values from SQL database in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003480/reading-values-from-sql-database-in-c-sharp)

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Requests where Complete = 0", connection))
{
    connection.Open();  
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader["Username"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(reader["Item"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(reader["Amount"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(reader["Complete"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Connexion to a database, example can be found here:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/21636/how-do-you-connect-to-a-sql-database-using-c

```
try
{
     SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=192.168.0.100,1433;database=Northwind;User id=Paladine;Password=;");
     thisConnection.Open();
     SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
     thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers";
     SqlDataReader thisReader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();
     while (thisReader.Read())
     {
              Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", thisReader["CustomerID"], thisReader["CompanyName"]);
     }
     thisReader.Close();
     thisConnection.Close();
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sharing the code but there are many vaiables undefined.

Comment: I changed my code accordingly. You should see now more information about different variables. The reason why I did it like that was to allow creating multiple tables in your powerpoint presentation, means, that if your rows from your DB are 100, you'll split them in different tables in powerpoint and also, if you want to limit the amount of columns to be visible. Also, I added information for the connexion to database and to read the data, and take choose rows that you want to use and to create a table with the column size related.

Comment: Did you finally found a solution or a perfect approach with the code I submitted?