# How to get a cell value from SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql

[image: ScreenShot]

I am new to SQL . As shown in the screenshot (SQL table) I want to get the circled cell value (3.4000) from this table and save it in a variable in C#. I just need the query and how to save it in a variable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: `select Price2 From Pizza where PizzaType = 'Hawaiian'`

Comment: W3Schools has a great introduction tutorial for SQL: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit generalized case. Providing that the RDBMS is *MS SQL* (if it's not your case, use appropriate *Connection* and *Command* classes instead of `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` ones) and you want `Decimal value` as a result

```
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString)) {
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand q = con.CreateCommand()) {
      q.CommandText = String.Format(
        @"select {0}
            from MyTable -- put actual table name here
           where PizzaType = @prmPizzaType", "Price2");

      q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmPizzaType", "Hawaiian");

      using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (reader.Read()) {
          // you may want to check if value is NULL: reader.IsDBNull(0)
          Decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[0]);

          if (reader.Read()) {
            //TODO: At least 2 values: put your code here
          }
        }
        else {
          //TODO: no such value: put your code here
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko .can I remove the column name of ( Price2) in query and put a variable so I can control the column name? how can I do it?

Comment: @Serena: no you can't put *bind variable* for that task, but you can use *formatting* (see my edit)

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @var float;
SET @var=(select Price2 from table where pizzaType='Hawaiian')
```

Answer (score 1):

The query for this would be something along the lines of

```
select Price2 from <tablename> where PizzaType = "Hawaiian"
```

As far as storing the value, I believe this question will help with that: [Reading values from SQL database in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003480/reading-values-from-sql-database-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible anymore like that. You need to store your query result in a DataGridView table, then take whatever you want from the DataGridView easily.