# Can I connect from my C# desk top application to an SQL Server database on Sharepoint without a web service?

Tags: c#, sql, sharepoint

I have created a desktop application in C# with an SQL Server database that holds my departments quotations. We now have a Sharepoint site and I will have to store this data there so that my coworkers abroad can use this app and add, query data themselves. I am familiar with reading data from web services using JSON, but not sure if creating a web service is necessary for an application to connect to a database stored on a server. Do I simply build an HTTP request with credentials to the Sharepoint site, then add the directory folder to the header and query the database?

Comment: Are you trying to pull data from your database and push into SharePoint?

Comment: No, I want the SQL Server database set up on SharePoint, then my desktop app retrieves or insert data into the database.

Comment: What do you mean by "set up on SharePoint?" Do you want your database on the same sql instance as the SharePoint databases? That should be no problem.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I want my database set up on the same sql  instance as the SharePoint site. my concern is how I will read and insert data from my desktop app, which now communicates to the database locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to create a service to access a database on a server.
What you are actually asking is how to read from (write to) database on C#. As I understand you already have an access to the database (user account with granted access and password). You will need to use ADO.NET - it's a technology for data access.

You will utilize SqlConnection,  SqlDataReader and SqlCommand classes.
check for example this example:
[Reading values from SQL database in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003480/reading-values-from-sql-database-in-c-sharp)

There is a newer technology from Microsoft called Entity Framework. It provides better solution for working with databases. Use it if you need to work with many tables and complicated queries.

Comment: Thanks. I currently use System.Data.Sqlclient for reading and writing to local databases. Not sure, after posting credentials, how to code the connection string.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/ - here you will find all the formats of connection strings. (in your case it's probably Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;)

Answer (score 0):

First, you or your dba need to backup/restore your desktop app's database to the same instance SharePoint is connected to. If you don't want to migrate existing data, create a new database using the same schema.

Next you'll want to create a sql user account that you can use in your connection string. Update your desktop app's connection string to use the new sql instance, username, and password.