# To set image url by converting byte to string and access other values from database stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, web

The stored procedure:

```
create procedure spGetImageId
    @Id int 
as 
Begin 
    select imageData 
    from uploadTable 
    where ID = @Id
End
```

C# code calling it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CHTproductionConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetImageId", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter paramID = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@Id",
            Value = Request.QueryString["ID"]
        };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramID);

        con.Open();
        byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;
    }
}
```

It is viewing uploaded image from the database and id is reading from the url. If I change my stored procedure to

```
create procedure spGetImageId
    @Id int 
as 
Begin 
    select title, description, imageData 
    from uploadTable 
    where ID = @Id
End
```

How can I access title and description by adding inside this code? Image changes with the change of id in the url.

The process is working. I just need to access title and description

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading values from SQL database in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003480/reading-values-from-sql-database-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have already given you an answer, but I thought splitting everything up should be a good advice.

Creating a method for bits of code that you'll probably need to reuse is a good practice. Executing a stored procedure often qualifies.

```
public string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CHTproductionConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }
}

public DataTable GetDataTableFromSproc(string sproc, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sproc, con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Then you've got a reusable method to call like so

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[1];
    parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]) };

    DataTable dt = this.GetDataTableFromSproc("spGetImageId", parameters);

    string title = dt.Rows[0]["title"].ToString();
    string description = dt.Rows[0]["description"].ToString();
    Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["imageData"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar
```

This is going to return you the first column of the first row returned. This is useful if you just need to get a single thing from a procedure, but in your case, you need to get multiple.

To do this, you need to use a SqlDataAdapter. Without refactoring your code, you can do the following. Although, I would suggest splitting out into a function that is used to retrieve the data and another that loads it into an object you can use.

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CHTproductionConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet TempData = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetImageId", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter paramID = new SqlParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "@Id",
       Value = Request.QueryString["ID"]
    };
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramID);
    con.Open();
    Adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    Adapter.Fill(TempData);
    string title = TempData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["title"].ToString();
    string description = TempData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["description"].ToString();
    string imageBytes = TempData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["imageData"].ToString();
    string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes );
    Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;
}
```

Comment: You must type a lot quicker than I.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem when trying to get the extra data is that `ExecuteScalar()` only returns the first column of the first row from what the recordset. To retrieve more than that requires the use of the `ExecuteReader()` method and using a DataReader,  DataTable, or DataAdapter to go through the set.

Other changes:

- Request.QueryString returns a string within an object and can be null. If someone should alter the string to text it will throw an error when the SQL executes. I added in 'int ImageID` to contain this
- I added in string variables and hoisted them for the other data (title, desc)
- Utilized try/catch/finally
- Did a null check on the image data prior to assigning to the Image control. The Title & Description values are there as well for your convenience,
- I replaced the distinct Sql Parameter with the direct `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()` method.

This is how it looks now:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CHTproductionConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    int ImageID;
    string ImgTitle;
    string ImgDesc;
    string ImgBytes;
    string strBase64;

    if (!int.TryParse((string)Request.QueryString["ID"]), out ImageID) {
        // STOP: querystring is not a number
    } 
    else {
        using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(cs)) {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetImageId", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ImageID);

            try {
                con.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read()) {
                    ImgTitle = reader[0].ToString();
                    ImgDesc = reader[1].ToString();
                    ImgBytes = reader[2].ToString();
                    strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ImgBytes);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                // handle exception
            }
            finally {
                cmd.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    if (strBase64 != null) {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;

        // utilize ImgTitle
        // utilize ImgDesc
    }
}
```